# Antivirus locking files

Tags: virus, malware, anti-virus

I have both MalwareBytes and Norton Internet Security on my home PC, and run scans regularly. Needless to say it takes some time to do a complete scan, but I run NIS first then when that's finished I run MalwareBytes.

Do either of these programs, when scanning a file, lock the file and then attempt to scan it? Suppose if I run both NIS and MalwareBytes at the same time and Norton scans a file that MalwareBytes is attempting to scan, will MalwareBytes ignore it and move on?

If so, assuming NIS determined the file isn't a virus, it could still potentially be malware, but MalwareBytes failed to catch it because NIS locked the file while it was scanning.

Comment: Are you running real-time scanning with both AV products?

Comment: @music2myear - With MB, you have to pay extra for that, so, right now, No. but Norton is real-time

Comment: Malwarebytes and NIS are compatible with one another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best practices demand that you only run a single AV product in Realtime, that is the full-time always-on scanner that watches over the system while it is running.

It is fine to have more than one security product installed and periodically run manual scans with them, but only one should be running realtime.

In your setup you should leave choose either MBAM or NIS to run realtime and disable all always-on functions of the other.

The reason for this is more or less as you surmise: The realtime scanning function has informed the OS that it is to receive every file as it is requested and before the requesting application receives it. When more than one AV product is running realtime they will interfere with each other.

**Based on your response,** I'm guessing you have nothing to worry about.

A manual scan takes as long as it must and doesn't generally worry about how long it may take to receive a file or how long it takes to scan the file.

Yes, when MBAM requests a file to scan it, NIS is jumping in there first and is scanning the file before handing it off to MBAM, but then MBAM will do its thing on the file and move on. MBAM has no need to get the file before NIS is done with it, and so will wait until it receives the file during its manual scans.

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, if NIS is scanning a file, and MB attempts to scan, MB will skip because Norton in blocking it?

Comment: lots of files might be currently locked by applications and the OS while you do a full scan. AV sofware only reads very small parts of files, so their "locks" to only take nanoseconds. Sounds pretty unlikely that they will interfere each other.

Comment: MBAM features are different when you have a subscription for it.  MBAM is also not an AV, and is compatible, with NIS. My suggestion schedule one program to start scanning several hours after the first.  MBAM doesn't really have real-time unless you pay for it.